# Handle LinkedHashMap. How update array of a particular key

Tags: anylogic

I have a problem with linkedHashMap.
I built a collection as follows:

```
int v[]={0,0,0,0,0};
collection.put("A",v);
collection.put("B",v);
collection.put("C",v);
collection.put("D",v);
```

I have agents with two parameters: p1 is a value between ("A","B","C","D") and p2 an integer value between (0 and 4).For each agent that enters the flow I want to update the collection to the key P1 at the position of the index indicated by P2.
The code I wrote to do it is as follows:

```
collection.get(agent.P1)[agent.P2]++;
```

The error is as follows: The increment is at the correct location, but for all keys.
The output obtained is in image attached

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, think about it: you change `v`. But `v` appears in all of your collection's values, it is the same `v`. (google "Java pass by reference versuc value"). So if you change `v` in one place, all other places "looking at" `v` will also find it changed.

To "split them up", you need to instantiate your collection differently, such that each value is its own int array:

```
collection.put("A",new int[]{0,0,0,0});
collection.put("B",new int[]{0,0,0,0});
collection.put("C",new int[]{0,0,0,0});
collection.put("D",new int[]{0,0,0,0});
```